# StdRegProv WMI Class and the GetStringValue method not returning a result

Tags: vbscript

I'm having a problem with the following code in VBScript using the StdRegProv WMI Class and the GetExpandedStringValue and GetStringValue methods:

```
' Name the standard reg provider
sRegProv = "\\.\root\cimv2:StdRegProv"
Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!" & _
    sRegProv)
' OS is a 64-bit computer, and we need to check all paths
' Do the 32-bit stuff, as most things these days are 32-bit
sKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
' Fill arrKeys with every value under sKeyPath
oReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sKeyPath, arrKeys
' step through each key until we find the one we want
For Each subKey in arrKeys
    ' Set the full key path to the next key
    sFullKeyPath = sKeyPath & subKey
    ' Wscript.echo "Checking key:   " & subKey
    ' Set the sDisplayName variable to the value in the key
    oReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sFullKeyPath, "DisplayName", sDisplayName
    Wscript.Echo "Found " & sDisplayName & " in key " & subKey
    If sDisplayName = sAppName Then
        Wscript.Echo "Found value: " & sDisplayName
        oReg.GetExpandedStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sFullKeyPath, "UninstallString", sUninstallString
        GetRegUninstallString = sUninstallString
        ' Exit the function; we've found what we're looking for
        Exit Function
    End If
Next
```

My problem is that the GetStringValue call is not returning a value at all, and neither is GetExpandedStringValue. I've tried this without the logic for checking the name, and several other things. This is all part of a larger function.

Things you won't see in this code are where I declared the constants, and the Function itself, which are here:

```
const HEKY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
```

The function has an input parameter of sAppName, which is where that value is being set. When I set it, I'm using proper quoting rules (i.e., Microsoft Office ProfessionalPlus 2013 is "Microsoft Office ProfessionalPlus 2013", for example).

Please help. We have an issue with an uninstaller not being consistent across my company, and I'd like to programmatically approach the problem so we can resolve it once and for all because of the differences. I'd like to deploy this script using Microsoft SCCM 2007, and it will work beautifully, IF I can get the issues resolved with verifying the app name and then grabbing the uninstall value.

Most of my search results have been related to people not providing an out parameter in the call to GetStringValue. I have referenced the following MSDN articles:
[StdRegProv (WMI Class),](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393664(v=vs.85).aspx)
[GetStringValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390788(v=vs.85).aspx)

Thanks for any replies in advance. I'm sure it's something silly. By the way, OS is Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a line to the code here to determine what the result of query sFullKeyPath was, and it turns out it was 2, which is the error for non-existent key. So, changing the following solved my problem:

```
sFullKeyPath = sKeyPath & "\" & subKey
```

Once that was changed, the rest of the script worked. The only items that failed completely after that were registry keys that didn't have a "DisplayName" property.

I'm posting this as an answer so that hopefully people can read and see the result.